# creating site backups via command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface, backup

I have a php script that is run via cron whose purpose is to tar up an entire directory. However my issue is it seems to just be creating an empty tar file??

```
 exec("tar -zcvf abcd.com-dir-".date('Y-m-d').".tar.gz var/www/html/abcd.com");
```

I confirmed the full path to the website is var/www/html/abcd.com

any other suggestions on what might be causing the code to just create an empty .tar.gz file?

Comment: Try using `/var/www/html/abcd.com` (mind the first `/ `)

Comment: Why wrap this in PHP? Just run the tar from cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the first slash in `/var...`

So, you can use

```
exec("tar -zcvf abcd.com-dir-".date('Y-m-d').".tar.gz /var/www/html/abcd.com");
```

Or, you can just add the command directly, without the need of PHP

```
tar -zcvf abcd.com-dir-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz /var/www/html/abcd.com
```